# Encouraging recurrent users to +1 (or Facebook Like)

Tags: google, search-engines, javascript, social-media, google-plus-one

I want to display a message to users who have visited my site 5 times, but have not yet +1'ed or Like'd to please do so. I guess javascript and a cookie are likely required. But have no idea how to go about doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use facebook or google +1 [content lock plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-like-content-locker/). You need a custom edit to this type of plugin to see if the users are coming regularly to same page or to the root domain. Then you can open content lock or pop-up box for the like or +1. This plugin is just starting point for this, you have to work on the rest to get what you want.